# Decrypt/use config values stored as config_backend_encrypted in magento

Tags: magento

I'm working on a shipping module.
In `system.xml` I set some fields to be `backend_encrypted`. Here is the node:

```
<client_id translate="label">
     <label>Client ID</label>
     <frontend_type>obscure</frontend_type>
     <backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_encrypted</backend_model>
     <sort_order>10</sort_order>
     <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
     <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
     <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</client_id>
```

I need that value to pass using cURL to shipping API but, when I try to retrieve it using `$this->getConfigData('client_id');`, it come out encrypted.

I was looking in other modules and I see values stored the same but somehow, they manage to get the right value.

Any idea how to get it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Just use `Mage::helper('core')->decrypt($this->getConfigData('client_id'));`

Comment: works, thanks. but why I haven't see any reference to decrypt on any other module? And if you can help, I'm using it wrong, where it's not supposed to be?

Comment: You are doing everything right. If you will search Magento code for "decrypt" you will get plenty of references.

Answer (score 36):

In order to use `$this->getConfigData('client_id');` without manually decrypting it, you need to update your config.xml by adding `<client_id backend_model="adminhtml/system_config_backend_encrypted" />`, see example below

In your config.xml

```
...
    <default>
        <carriers>
            <magepal>
                ......
                <client_id backend_model="adminhtml/system_config_backend_encrypted" />
            </magepal>
        </carriers>
    </default>
</config>
```

Comment: Adding this will transparently decrypt the configuration values, which I suppose in 9 out of 10 cases is what is actually wanted.

While Tim's solution works, I think this is the more correct answer.

Comment: ^^ Whilst the accepted answer 'works', this definitely does seem more 'correct'.